# How to stop exception

Tags: c#, winforms, error-handling

How do I prevent the program from going into the try-catch blocks if I cancel something?
Ex:

```
try{
  int i=int.Parse(Interaction.InputBox("BlahBlahBlah"));
}
catch{
  //error handling
  return
}
```

But what if I press "Cancel" or the X on the top? It goes to the try-catch, and considers this an exception. So it does the error handling. How do I stop this?

Comment: Are you using winforms?

Comment: yes, I am using winforms, since I am using `Interaction.InputBox()` function.

Comment: not sure what you're asking ... what's the block leading to this?

Comment: Is this single thread or do u have a background worker processing this logic?

Comment: The question is: How to stop the program flow from getting into the try-catch block if I press "Cancel" on the `InputBox`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the documentation ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.interaction.inputbox(v=vs.110).aspx ) an empty string is returned if the user cancels.

You'll want this:

```
do {
    String text = Interaction.InputBox("Enter a number");
    if( text == "" ) return -1;
    Int32 number;
    if( Int32.TryParse( text, out number ) ) return number;
} while( true );
```

This way it will keep on prompting the user until a valid integer number is entered or they Cancel the dialog.

Comment: This is exactly how you did it back in VB6 days.

Comment: Well what where you planning on doing with `i` in your old code? you could always wrap the above code inside a function that returns a `int` and just do `int i = YourNewFunction()`.